# Simple HTML page not loading Javascript Hello World

Tags: javascript, html

As part of a very basic introduction to programming I am instructed to make a simple HTML file with the following code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a very simple HTML page</p>
    <script src="script.js"</script>
</body>
```

The file is saved as container.html

In the same folder is a file called script.js which contains the following:

```
alert(“Hello World”);
```

When I load the HTML file into Safari 7.0.2 it correctly displays "this is a very simple HTML page" and appears to load something but the Javascript alert "Hello World" does not appear in a pop up style window as it does on the instructors computer.

I have checked all settings to make sure Javascript is enabled and popup blocker is off. I've also tried loading in Firefox and Crome but it does not work correctly.

As instructed in the course I am coding using TextEdit and viewing the script through the container.html file.

Comment: wrong quotation marks? `" "` instead of `“ ”`

Comment: looks like a missing closing brace `<script src="script.js"</script>` => `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “ " quotes in javascript?](/q/45766066/4642212), and [JavaScript: a simple 'compare' function not working?](/q/16726570/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a very simple HTML page</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You forgot the closing tag on the script.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you close your `<script>` tag.

eg

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script> //to include jQuery
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Also

`“` and `”` should be `"` or `'`.

They won't work otherwise.

Also, stick in a `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No closing tag '**>**' of script tag

Modify below line:

```
<script src="script.js"</script>
```

with

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget the ">"

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close the script tag (your HTML looks to be missing the >):

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

That's all that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Be carreful at closing your script tag !

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in you code

**Your html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a very simple HTML page</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Your JS**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    alert("Hello world");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Deselect the smart quotes option in textedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7a53.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Link-only answers are discouraged. Always try to include essential parts of the linked page in your answer.